# SQL Script to change encoding of text in a column of a given row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, encoding, utf-8

I'm working on an application with a UTF-8 DB, but some of the rows / columns contain text in ISO-8859-15 still (don't ask me why, I don't know how it happened exactly).

So, characters like "é" become "Ã©".

Is there a way in Sql to retrieve texts with the wrong encoding (simple search on Ã© - that's not my problem) in order to **save this text with the right encoding**.

Something like :

- Sql search on a column of a table : gives a String and an id in the table (or multiple couples).
- Transform String to UTF-8
- Update the column at the given id with the new String.

All this with an SQL script.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to change encoding of text at given row and column using :

```
convert_from(convert_to(the_text_you_need_to_change, 'ISO-8859-15'), 'UTF8');
```